# Windows 10 unable to time sync, time service is greyed out

Tags: windows-10, permissions, time

I am using a Windows 10 machine which is unable to sync time automatically.

Clicking on "Sync now" on the Date & Time Settings produces an error "Time synchronization failed". The problem has been going on for a long time, as the last successful sync is shown to have happened 1 year ago.

The Time Service logs in Event Viewer are empty. Aside from that, Event Viewer contains no message connected to time synchronization.

In Services, the Windows Time service is set to "Manual (Trigger Start)" and its status is blank. When clicking on the service, everything is greyed out, so it cannot be started manually. (See screenshot below.)

[image]

Launching a command prompt as admin and trying to operate on the service via CLI produce the following errors:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>net stop w32time
The Windows Time service is not started.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3521.


C:\WINDOWS\system32>net start w32time
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.


C:\WINDOWS\system32>w32tm /unregister
The following error occurred: Access is denied. (0x80070005)

C:\WINDOWS\system32>w32tm /register
The following error occurred: Access is denied. (0x80070005)
```

The Task Scheduler reports the same error 0x5 for task `SynchronizeTime`. Details of tasks `SynchronizeTime` and `ForceSynchronizeTime` are all greyed out.

I have run DISM and SFC [as suggested here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system), and it did not find any integrity violation:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.18362.1

Image Version: 10.0.18362.657

[==========================100.0%==========================] The restore operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.
```

EDIT 1:

Here's the output of `sc sdshow w32time`, converted via `ConvertFrom-SddlString -Sddl "<output>"`:

```
Owner            :
Group            :
DiscretionaryAcl : {NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE: AccessAllowed (CreateDirectories, GenericExecute, ListDirectory, Read,
                   ReadAttributes, ReadExtendedAttributes, ReadPermissions, WriteAttributes), NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:
                   AccessAllowed (ChangePermissions, CreateDirectories, Delete, DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles,
                   ExecuteKey, FullControl, GenericAll, GenericExecute, GenericRead, GenericWrite, ListDirectory,
                   Modify, Read, ReadAndExecute, ReadAttributes, ReadExtendedAttributes, ReadPermissions,
                   TakeOwnership, Traverse, Write, WriteAttributes, WriteData, WriteExtendedAttributes, WriteKey),
                   BUILTIN\Administrators: AccessAllowed (CreateDirectories, GenericExecute, ListDirectory, Read,
                   ReadAttributes, ReadExtendedAttributes, ReadPermissions, WriteAttributes)}
SystemAcl        : {Everyone: SystemAudit FailedAccess (ChangePermissions, CreateDirectories, Delete,
                   DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles, ExecuteKey, FullControl, GenericAll, GenericExecute, GenericRead,
                   GenericWrite, ListDirectory, Modify, Read, ReadAndExecute, ReadAttributes, ReadExtendedAttributes,
                   ReadPermissions, TakeOwnership, Traverse, Write, WriteAttributes, WriteData,
                   WriteExtendedAttributes, WriteKey)}
RawDescriptor    : System.Security.AccessControl.CommonSecurityDescriptor
```

EDIT 2:

I've tried to apply different permissions to the service (see @Robert's comment):

```
sc sdset w32time "D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)(A;;CCLCSWRPLOCRRC;;;LS)(A;;CCSWWPLORC;;;LS)"
```

but it fails with this error:

```
[SC] OpenService FAILED 5:

Access is denied.
```

All the commands above were launched on a Command Prompt run as Administrator.

EDIT 3, 24/2/2021: One year after my post, the problem went mysteriously away by itself (somehow). Now the clock appears synchronized (last time sync marked coincides with the last boot). Manually trying to time sync by clicking on "Sync now" on the Date & Time Settings still produces an error "Time synchronization failed", but at least it automatically syncs, and that's good enough for me.

Comment: Have you try to set different time server? `0.pool.ntp.org` for example?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of Dependencies?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Yes. The problem is clearly in a faulty Time Service.

Comment: @dr01 - Services can have other services that are required to be running before they can start.  If your asking for the definition of the word, I am not a dictionary, but I still need that screenshot to answer your question.

Comment: @dr01 - Look at your screenshot.  There is a `Dependencies` tab.  Click on it and provide a screenshot.  It does not matter, I click it on my system, since you didn't understand what I wanted.  So disregard my request.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, my mistake. I completely missed the tab. I clicked on it, it shows no dependencies for the service.

Comment: Is a AppLocker policy active for this computer? Or are there any other GPOs active that could affect the service start?

Comment: @Robert I haven't set any. I would be very surprised if there were, considered that the time service is a standard Windows service.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the service? In a shell run `sc sdshow w32time` and the output can be converted in a powershell using `ConvertFrom-SddlString -Sddl "<output of sc sdshow w32time>"`

Comment: @Robert Done, added the output to the post.

Comment: @dr01 That is strange I have compared the output with two Win10 1909 machines (one Home stand-alone, the other Enterprise + domain). And for both the output was the same and at large parts different than yours. If you feel brave you can try to apply my sddl settings via `sc sdset w32time "D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)(A;;CCLCSWRPLOCRRC;;;LS)(A;;CCSWWPLORC;;;LS)"`

Comment: @Robert Thanks. For now I'd rather like to understand if/why my settings are incorrect before changing them.

Comment: @dr01 IMHO the most likely answer is a GPO similar to [this case](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e1d2d01a-6384-43ea-b838-f9384947ffea).

Comment: you get a permission error. have you tried running the cmd prompt as administrator? In the Search box, type command prompt. In the list of results, right-click Command Prompt. and then click Run as administrator. then retry the command: net start w32time

Comment: @dr01 When you run the command prompt as an administrator, does the title bar start with *Administrator:*?

Comment: Suggestions: (1) Check computer clock and timezone, (2) Ensure registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time` item `ImagePath` contains "C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k LocalService". (3) Set Windows Time service to Startup of "Automatic (Delayed Start)", reboot, and wait a few minutes. (4) Try the solutions in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1200156/windows-time-not-synchronizing-access-is-denied-error). (5) If all fails, you might need to do a [Repair Install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: @Steven and others: yes, I ran the Command Prompt as administrator, and this is reflected in the title bar. Thanks everybody for the useful comments.

Comment: @Robert Please copy and paste your comments to an answer, so it is easier to find for future visitors of StackExchange, and you can get reputation.

Comment: @harrymc 1) They're on "set automatically". 2) It's "%SystemRoot%\system32\svchost.exe -k LocalService" so I guess it's ok. 3) As said on my post, Time Service properties are not editable. 4) No effect, see my post. 5) That's what I wanted to avoid, since it can bork badly other parts of my machine. Thanks for your suggestions anyway!

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT The configuration of external time servers is ok and your screenshot matches my registry. The problem is the time service on my machine, which is not running and which hence cannot connect to any time server.

Comment: @Robert I have tried to apply the permission changes you suggested, and it fails with this error: `[SC] OpenService FAILED 5: Access is denied.` (also added to my post). Thanks for trying anyway.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Tried to run the same command multiple times, no change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your computer participates in a domain, it is normal that the properties
of the Windows Time system service are not modifiable.
They would be grayed out by default and the time is synchronized with the domain controller, as required for Kerberos authentication.
You should in this case address yourself to the administrator of the domain.

If your computer is not on a domain, check first
if this also happens when booting in Safe mode.
If the Properties are still not modifiable, then there is a problem with
Windows. Otherwise, some installed product is causing the problem.

If this also happens in Safe mode, check
in the Local Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`)
if the permissions have not been corrupted.

Position to
*Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment*. Check here the item `Change the system time` whose property should be
`LOCAL SERVICE,Administrators,NT SERVICE\autotimesvc`.
Check also `Change the time zone` whose value should be
`LOCAL SERVICE,Administrators,Users,Device Owners`.

If this is not the problem, to set all Windows components to a known state
would require to
[Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).
This is exactly the same as doing a major Windows upgrade, so you should take
similar precautions, but in most cases has no bad effects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My machine is not on a domain. Unfortunately Microsoft, in their infinite wisdom, decided that Win10 Home users shall not have access to gpedit. Third-party tools such as Policy Plus (https://github.com/Fleex255/PolicyPlus) are not stable enough for me yet.

Comment: Your suggestion that some other third-party installed program might be causing the issue is good. I've tried to disable AV and FW (after physically disconnecting the machine from the network), but unfortunately the issue persists. I've always been extremely careful on my machines and avoided installing programs unless I really needed them and knew what they were doing.

Comment: I have recommended Policy Plus in several posts and it always did the job. If not, you could use ntrights.exe from the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit ([direct link](https://winaero.com/download.php?view.2240)) with `ntrights +r SeSystemtimePrivilege -u "User or Group"`. See [description](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/92910-allow-prevent-users-groups-change-time-windows-10-a.html#option3).

Comment: Due to important reasons I cannot do these experiments with the machine right now. I'm willing to do so when possible. For now I'm awarding the bounty because it has expired. Will let you know.

Comment: No problem, let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is obviously Windows Time will not start since its set to manual and greyed out.

However, I finally devised a solution.  Click Run, then type Regedit.

Go to Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time

Modify the Start dword and change the value to 2.

Restart your computer.  While Windows time service is still grey out, we have been able to finally start it.

Now go to Date / Time by right clicking your time on bottom right corner.  And then click Adjust date/time.  Then set time automatic and time zone automatic.

You may and will then see a spinning blue circle as Windows 10 is using all of your CPU's power to change the time to automatic.  Give it some time to complete the operation.  It may take up to 5 min even if you have custom built gaming machine.  However, it will in fact finish and your time will now be automatic and working again.

So this solution of changing the start value may and probably will work with any greyed out service that you need to start.

Answer (score 2):

[@Robert in comments](https://superuser.com/questions/1530760/windows-10-unable-to-time-sync-time-service-is-greyed-out#comment2321952_1530760) pointed out HOW to check permissions of service which appear to be incorrect on your PC & [he's given you steps on how to fix](https://superuser.com/questions/1530760/windows-10-unable-to-time-sync-time-service-is-greyed-out#comment2323425_1530760) which you have declined. I am thinking its unlikely you will find the answer to WHY that service got messed up TBH. However you may want to update/rephrase your question to indicate what you are trying to solve exactly: the problem itself or the reason why the problem occurred. Below is some info I can provide that may be helpful:

- Win10 v1607 Enterprise x64 here in domain & my W32Time service is manual, entirely greyed out, & no dependencies so I speculate that is normal
- WinMerge screenshot comparing your W32Time service security ACL vs mine:
  [image]

Answer (score 2):

For anybody googling:

I've had this same exact issue as described in the post and I followed ***every*** single suggestion with ***exactly*** the same results as described by the original poster, down to the letter. I've been trying to fix this issue on and off since 2019 with no success and since I wasn't willing to reinstall windows, I gave up and resorted to setting the time manually. However, I've finally found a workaround that works (for me).

NetTime works for me. I'm glad to finally have my windows clock back to an accurate & self-updating state, after 3 years.

https://www.timesynctool.com/

Hope this helps someone else with the same problem out there, who just wants to have their time correct. The actual problem with the service isn't fixed and mine didn't solve itself like the original post, and honestly I'm not too bothered as long as my windows clock is correct.